# Get Total Value From Second Table and Display it in Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one HTML/PHP Table in which I am displaying value from one of my MySQL database table called tbl_project. It have example fields like id, name and quantity. Its displaying fine using below query

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_projects";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
```

and Table Body Like below

```
<tbody>
    <?php   
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { 

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i+1?></td>              

    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['quantity'];?></td>

    ?> 
</tbody>
```

Now I have one another table called `tbl_project_quantity which have fields like id, project_id(its global as tbl_project), user_id and quantity.` 
I want show one another column in my table called Quantity Received in which I want show `Total Quantity Received from all users where project_id is same as id in tbl_project`

I have read that it's possible with LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN but I am new in PHP and MYSQL so don't getting it working. It will be very helpful for me if someone can help me for that. 
Thanks

Comment: Just get the sum in PHP `$total = sum(array_column($result, '__COLUMN__'))`; Alternatievely, you may just add a column to your select fields: `(SELECT SUM(__COLUMN__) FROM tbl_proejcts) AS total ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo could use a join

```
$qry="SELECT t1.name, t2.quantity
      FROM tbl_projects t1
      LEFT JOIN tbl_project_quantity t2 ON t1.id = t2.project_id";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer sir! Its nice but I am looking for calculate all rows Total from tbl_project_quantity where project_id is same as id in tbl_projects. I have also doubt about how to echo that value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it.
But your query will look something like this

```
select p.*,sum(pq.quantity) as total_quantity from tbl_projects p INNER JOIN tbl_projects_quantity pq ON p.id = pq.project_id group by p.id
```